# Custom search engine not working on android phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-custom-search

I am running google custom search in browser it works fine. It runs fine even in emulator in Phonegap but it gives network error or it shows blank screen when the same is run on android phone. or gives this error  "file:///google.com/cse?q=.... can not be found."

I am using google custom search v2 code.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: i am running through phonegap.. it should run on all the browsers... is it the problem of phonegap?

Comment: That’s because when used with PhoneGap the location of your source is a file. Therefore file is the protocol, but http(s) is required to get access to the service.

Comment: then what might be the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The code you get for v2 of custom search looks something like this:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'ENGINE_ID';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

What it roughly does is creating a tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=ENGINE_ID">
```

and inserts it before other scripts on your page. So you can skip this code altogether and manually insert the above tag (with your engine id) and only `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` to your HTML. If the connection from file:// to http:// is still not possible, download this script (http://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=ENGINE_ID) and serve it as local javascript file.

Comment: tried it is giving error                                                                        "Cannot call method 'execute' of null in file "filename.html?q=query"..

Comment: My js code is <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script>
var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
var query= unescape(temp[1]);
var myCallback = function() {
   google.search.cse.element.render(
        {div:'test',
          tag:'searchresults-only'
        });
   google.search.cse.element.getElement('q').execute(query);
 };
window.__gcse = {
  parsetags: 'explicit',
  callback: myCallback
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx="id"></script>
</head>

Comment: my html is <body>
<div class="gcse-searchbox" id="test">
<!--<gcse:searchresults-only gname="q" autoSearchOnLoad="true"></gcse:searchresults-only>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. An one-line change in JavaScript made the file:// error go away:

```
// This line must take place before initializing GCSE
window.IS_GOOGLE_AFS_IFRAME_ = true;
```

Verified on both iOS and Android Cordova environments.

Comment: An alternate fix in Java: `@Override`
`public void onReceivedError(final int errorCode, final String description, final String failingUrl) { return; }`